# Android app not working with 3G connection

Tags: android, network-protocols

I am facing a rather weird problem with my android app. It is a very basic app which connects to a server and posts requests.

When the phone is switched on initially, and the app is started with only a 3G connection - the server connection times-out each and every time. The moment i connect to a wifi network it works. And to top it off - if i switch back to 3G after this , it works fine. I am very confused as to what is going on.

Do I need to turn on some parameter in order for the app to work without wifi and only 3G in the first try? Any insight would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you checked your 3G connection works for other thing when the phone is initially switched on? Can you browse?

Comment: Yes, i just tried opening the browser and it worked..went back to app and the connection timed out!